# com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.model.CNAMEAlreadyExistsException

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, cname

I am trying to add 2 CNAMEs to my CloudFront distribution, but I am getting this error message:

com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.model.CNAMEAlreadyExistsException: One or more of the CNAMEs you provided are already associated with a different resource. (Service: AmazonCloudFront; Status Code: 409; Error Code: CNAMEAlreadyExists;

I don't have another CloudFront distrubution, and I don't think anyone else has a distribution with these names since they are very unique:

"www.plataformalatina.com" and "plataformalatina.com"

Can anyone please help?

Comment: I just checked a `nslookup` on the domain you posted, and it's not pointing to a CloudFront distribution?

Comment: In Route 53 I have two A records for www.plataformalatina.com and plataformalatina.com pointing to my distribution: "ALIAS d206mi07vh816s.cloudfront.net" What else do I need to do?

Comment: The propagation should be 60 seconds, so something in the configuration might be wrong

Comment: It might be because I'm not able to add the CNAME to my CloudFront distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted AWS support and turns out someone else had a CloudFront distribution associated with that CNAME.

Comment: See point 2 in my response and also "Did you get confirmation from AWS to know if they're or wild card is not added somewhere else?

"

Comment: Yes, I knew I probably needed to ask AWS but at that time I wasn't paying for AWS support so I couldn't ask them.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get confirmation from AWS to know if they're or wild card is not added somewhere else?

You can try this:

1. Try creating CNAME record instead of alias 
   www.plataformalatina.com CNAME dxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net

Try to add this www.plataformalatina.com to your Distribution.

If this works, remove alias for plataformalatina.com as well and try to add it to CloudFront.
CloudFront performs check before it allows you to add any CNAME and in case of Route53 alias record, it sees that it resolves to CloudFront IP address but it doesn't know where is it added.

2. If above doesn't work:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/resolve-cnamealreadyexists-error/

Follow above article and submit proof to Amazon that this domain belong to you and they're add the CNAME on half of you.

Comment: If I try to create a CNAME for plataformalatina.com poiting to my distribution I get "[RRSet of type CNAME with DNS name plataformalatina.com. is not permitted at apex in zone plataformalatina.com.]" so I created a CNAME for www.plataformalatina.com. That worked but still can't add www,plataformalatina.com as a CNAME to my distribution.

Comment: Yes, you can’t have cname for a apex domain, please try first with www and if it works , remove the cname for apex doamin and add it and if you’re able to add it, create alias record.